# Sparql views - query

Tags: view, sparql

I have made view (spraql view) called Person with fields: name, street adress, organization.., e-mail usign some foaf and schema ontology. But I cant find out how to specify sparql query. I need to get only people with specific adress for exmaple: person where adress is "road 1". Is there possibility to set up this?
... many thanks for your answers (and tutorials also)..

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to learn SPARQL then Leigh Feigenbaum's [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/) is a great place to start

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend you reading Bob DuCharme's ["Learning SPARQL"](http://learningsparql.com/) book.